# Generating permutations from a template

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, permutation

My goal is to create a general function that creates a two-dimensional vector filled with permutations (vector) based on a template given and on parameters, as follows:

- some positions of the vector have to be fixed, based on a template as a function parameter vector. For example, if the given template is `{0, 1, 0, -1, 3, -1}`, this means that permutations will only vary by the numbers in places of `-1`.
- `n`. `n-1` is the range of integers the permutation can include. E.g. if `n = 4`, only `0, 1, 2, 3` can appear in the vector
- `length`, which is the length of the vector

Note, that if a number from the template already appears in it, it will not be generated in the permutations.

So, to give an example:

```
n = 6, length = 5, template = {2, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1}
the permutations are:
{2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3}
{2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 4}
{2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5}
{2, 1, 0, 4, 0, 3}
{2, 1, 0, 4, 0, 4}
{2, 1, 0, 4, 0, 5}
{2, 1, 0, 5, 0, 3}
{2, 1, 0, 5, 0, 4}
{2, 1, 0, 5, 0, 5}
```

As you can see, the numbers are only generated in indexes 3 and 5 (places, where it was `-1`), also, the places to do not include `0, 1 or 2`, since they already appear in the template.

I need to generate these permutations without using the `<algorithm>` library.

I assume creating a recursive function is the best option, but I do not know how to move forward. Any suggestions would help.

Thanks

Comment: Try to break the problem down to smaller parts. You could start by generating the list of numbers that `-1` should be substituted with.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call these permutations. Usually permutations take a given "ordered/indexed" set and change the order. In this case, you seem to allow multiples of the elements in the set we are drawing from to fill the `-1` spots.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've offered no visible attempt, I assume it might be helpful for you to study some working code. This is in JavaScript (I hope it's producing the expected output). I hope it can help give you some ideas you could translate to C++.

```js
function f(template){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(template));

  var used = template.reduce((acc, x) => { if (x != -1) acc.add(x); return acc; }, new Set());

  console.log(`used: ${Array.from(used)}`);

  var needed = new Set(template.reduce((acc, x, i) => { if (!used.has(i)) acc.push(i); return acc; }, []));

  console.log(`needed: ${Array.from(needed)}`);

  var indexes = template.reduce((acc, x, i) => { if (x == -1) return acc.concat(i); else return acc; }, []);

  console.log(`indexes: ${indexes}`);

  function g(needed, indexes, template, i=0){
    if (i == indexes.length)
      return [template];

    var result = [];

    // Each member of 'needed' must appear in
    // each position, indexes[i]
    for (x of needed){
      let _template = template.slice();
      _template[ indexes[i] ] = x;

      result = result.concat(
        g(needed, indexes, _template, i + 1));
    }

    return result;
  }

  return g(needed, indexes, template);
}

var template = [2, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1];

var result = f(template);

var str = '\n';

for (let r of result)
  str += JSON.stringify(r) + '\n';

console.log(str);
```